# Widget in the app not appearing in the device?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

We have a problem with adding the widget to the screen.
Our app has 2 widgets and app is live in AppStore.

The problem that some users can see only 1 widget (randomly, and using the newest version of the app), some see both widgets. It is hard to debug as I see both widgets on my device.

Happened on iPhone 6S iOS 14, iPhone 11 iOS 14. I guess there are more users as well who can't see these widgets.

Any known issues?

Answer (score 10):

So I found the reason, so in future, if anyone has the same issues, might help:

1. Apple for today has some bugs related to the WidgetKit. If you want to see the widget in the widget menu, you must first open the app (after updating or installing) and then put the app to the background or kill the app
2. Now you are able to see the widget in the widget menu

Comment: I have the same issue with our testing device (iPhone 6S, iOS version 14.5). The widget is not showing in the widget menu when installing the app from TestFlight. Can confirm the above steps to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, that just helped me. Same issue on iOS 15

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and a few mistakes caused it.

- The widget development target was higher than the app target.
- The intent extension development target was higher than the app target.
- I didn't add the supported families.

```
 .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
```

Comment: The first solution worked for me: My real devices is running IOS15, and when I created the widget extension, I enabled 'Live Activity' which automatically sets it to IOS 16.4. Solved it by disabling Live activity until I get a device capable of running said version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by changing the size family. I was using .systemExtraLarge so I changed to .systemLarge.